# Advanced DynamicInvocation of arguments for a "Delegated Switch"

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

**Context**

In my free time, I wanted to develop a tools that will fulfill the following needs :

- Looping over a bit[] value to execute a determined method for each True.
- Easy to implement a new method and easy to call overall in case of new filter OR adding length to the bit[] values.

I called this need "Delegated Switch" but their is no real relation to `switch`...

---

**Needs**

I realized that I also want to give arguments to my methods (which could be different from a method to another). So I searched for solutions and found tricks to not have arguments using inheritance of `OperatorOnFilter`.

What I want to know is:

- Does it exist a way to do that without inheritance (changing `OperatorOnFilter`)?
- (Optionally if not, any architectural recommendation?)
- (Optionally, Delegate.DynamicInvoke() is a bit slow. Any better idea?)

---

**Existing Code**

```
public class OperatorOnFilter
{
    Dictionary<int, Delegate> Operations;
    public OperatorOnFilter() { Operations = new Dictionary<int, Delegate>(); }

    public void AddOrReplace(int numTraitement, Delegate Action)
    {
        if (Operations.ContainsKey(numTraitement))
            Operations[numTraitement] = Action;
        else
            Operations.Add(numTraitement, Action);
    }

    public void ApplyOperations(FilterManager Filter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Filter.Values.Count(); i++)
            if (Operations.ContainsKey(i) && Filter.Values[i])
                Operations[i].DynamicInvoke();
    }
}

public class FilterManager
{
    public bool[] Values;
    public FilterManager(int filtre)
    {
        List<bool> tmpList = new List<bool>();
        int i = 0;
        while (filtre >> i > 0)
        {
            tmpList.Add((filtre & (1 << i)) == (1 << i));
            i++;
        }
        Values = tmpList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
class Program
{
    static int theYes = 0;

    delegate void operate();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        OperatorOnFilter myOperators = new OperatorOnFilter();
        myOperators.AddOrReplace(0, (operate)delegate() { Console.Write("a"); theYes++; }); //1
        myOperators.AddOrReplace(1, (operate)delegate() { Console.Write("b"); theYes++; }); //2
        myOperators.AddOrReplace(2, (operate)delegate() { Console.Write("c"); theYes++; }); //4

        myOperators.ApplyOperations(new FilterManager(7));      //"abc" 7 = 1 + 2 + 4
        myOperators.ApplyOperations(new FilterManager(3));     //"ab" 3 = 1 + 2
        myOperators.ApplyOperations(new FilterManager(6));    //"bc" 6 = 2 + 4

        Console.WriteLine(theYes); // 7

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
// FINAL RESULT :
// abcabbc
// 7
```

Comment: I added an independant FilterManager to maybe change the way I'm mathematically looking for operations. Maybe for a later abstraction with interfaces/generics.

Comment: Still not very clear what you want. Invoke with argumengs? And where thise arguments will come from?

Comment: The arguments values and delegate called are from an independant project (here the `Program`). The idea is that you can store those delegate and invoke them with arguments set in the `Program` before `ApplyOperations` and called at `ApplyOperations`.

Comment: So, just store your arguments together with your delegate and invoke. Still not sure what the exact problem is.

Comment: The problem is basicly, I don't know how to store those parameters efficiently... Since it would look like a `params object[]` It will ask me to store it in a `Dictionnary<int, List<object>>` when I already have a `Dictionnary<int, Delegate>` ...

Comment: Well store in `Dictionary<int, Tuple<Delegate, object[]>>`, for example...

Comment: It's a solution indeed. I don't know how it will perform with a lot of dictionnary keys but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Erk comments and some self improvement. I found my answers using explicit parameters on delegate and on my AddOrReplace methods.

**Final Code** (Tuple is added since I work with .NET 3.5)

```
public class OperatorOnFilter
{
    Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, object[]>> Operations = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, object[]>>();
    List<Delegate> lstOperations = new List<Delegate>();

    public OperatorOnFilter() { }

    public void AddOrReplace(int numTraitement, Delegate Action, params object[] Arguments)
    {
        if (!lstOperations.Contains(Action))
            lstOperations.Add(Action);

        if (Operations.ContainsKey(numTraitement))
            Operations[numTraitement] = new Tuple<int, object[]>(lstOperations.IndexOf(Action), Arguments);
        else
            Operations.Add(numTraitement, new Tuple<int, object[]>(lstOperations.IndexOf(Action), Arguments));
    }

    public void ApplyOperations(FilterManager Filter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Filter.Values.Count(); i++)
            if (Operations.ContainsKey(i) && Filter.Values[i])
                lstOperations[Operations[i].First].DynamicInvoke(Operations[i].Second);
    }

}

public class FilterManager
{
    public bool[] Values;
    public FilterManager(int filtre)
    {
        List<bool> tmpList = new List<bool>();
        int i = 0;
        while (filtre >> i > 0)
        {
            tmpList.Add((filtre & (1 << i)) == (1 << i));
            i++;
        }
        Values = tmpList.ToArray();
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 First { get; private set; }
    public T2 Second { get; private set; }
    internal Tuple(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}

public static class Tuple
{
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> New<T1, T2>(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        var tuple = new Tuple<T1, T2>(first, second);
        return tuple;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
class Program
{
    static int theYes = 0;

    delegate void operate1();
    delegate void operate2(string a);
    delegate void operate3(string a, uint x);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        OperatorOnFilter myOperators = new OperatorOnFilter();
        myOperators.AddOrReplace(0, (operate1)delegate() { Console.Write("a"); theYes++; }); //1
        myOperators.AddOrReplace(1, (operate2)delegate(string a) { Console.Write(a); theYes++; }, "b"); //2
        myOperators.AddOrReplace(2, (operate3)delegate(string a, uint x) { for (uint j = 0U; j < x; j++) { Console.Write(a); theYes++; } }, "c", 3U); //4

        myOperators.ApplyOperations(new FilterManager(7));      //"abccc" 7 = 1 + 2 + 4
        myOperators.ApplyOperations(new FilterManager(3));     //"ab" 3 = 1 + 2
        myOperators.ApplyOperations(new FilterManager(6));    //"bccc" 6 = 2 + 4

        Console.WriteLine(theYes); // 11

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to write the function without specifying the number of parameters that you pass in.

There is a way to do this, using the [params keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229008(v=vs.100).aspx). There's also a good (and probably better) example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228391(v=vs.90).aspx

This can require you to declare at least the type of the argument that you will pass in. However, you can set that type as Object or a generic, or even use the Delegate type that you are already familiar with to pass in other functions.

If you do this, a function signature will be like:
public void AddOrReplace(Delegate Action, params int[] list){...}

And you would call it with:
myOperators.AddOrReplace((operate)delegate() { Console.Write("a"); theYes++; }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

Comment: For me to make it clear using the Test part. IIt would mean for general use to have `delegate void operate();` replaced by `delegate void operate(params object[] args);`
Won't it be impossible to make the cast `(operate)delegate() { /* blabla */ }` ?

Comment: Just checked... `params` even if correct at compiles time isn't working with `delegate`